# Verifying a solution of modular arithmetic question.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I was given the following practice question with the solution:

**A practice question: find $\phi(27)$ and use it to calculate  $300^{93} \pmod {27}$.**

Solution:
Since $\phi(27) = 18$, then:
$$(300^{93\pmod {18}}\pmod{27})\pmod{27}=(3^{93\pmod{18}})\pmod{27}=3^3\pmod{27} =0.$$

My question is: Based on what theorem we mod the exponent $93\pmod{18}$ and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all this stuff to compute $300^{93}\mod 27$: since $3^3=\equiv 0\mod 27$, we have
$$300^{93}=3^3 3^{90}100^{93}=0\cdot3^{90}100^{93}\equiv 0\mod 27.$$

Answer (score 0):

Apply the Lemma below, where all congruences are $\!\pmod m\,$ unless otherwise notated, and where we have employed standard [congruence arithmetic rules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

**Lemma** $\ $ If $\,\ \color{#c00}{a^N\equiv 1}\,\ $ then $\ J\equiv K\pmod N\ \Rightarrow\ a^J\equiv a^K$

**Proof** $\ \ J = K + IN\,\Rightarrow\, a^J \equiv a^{K+IN}\equiv a^K (\color{#c00}{a^N})^I\equiv a^K \color{#c00}1^I\equiv a^K$

Comment: **Remark** $\ $ The proof works even when $\,I < 0\,$ because $\,a\,$ is invertible by $\,a^N\equiv 1.\ $ Alternatively we can assume $\,I\ge 0\,$ by choosing $\, J\ge K\,$ wlog. $\ \ $